# How to find beta values in Logistic Regression model with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Based on the Logistic Regression function:

[image: logit]

I'm trying to extract the following values from my model in **scikit-learn**.

[image: beta0]
 and [image: beta1]

Where [image: beta0] is the intercept and [image: beta1] is the regression coefficient. (as per the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression))

Now, I think I can get [image: beta0] by doing `model.intercept_` but I've been struggling to get [image: beta1]. Any ideas?

Comment: Be careful; `sklearn` has a default regularization coefficient built-in that may not produce expected log odds ratios.

Comment: @andrew_reece anyway to remove/change it?

Comment: Sure, just adjust the `C` parameter when initializing. You can also cross check betas with `statsmodels` logistic reg. output, or with R.

Answer (score 5):

You can access the coefficient of the features using `model.coef_`.

It gives a list of values that corresponds to the values `beta1`, `beta2` and so on. The size of the list depends on the amount of explanatory variables your logistic regression uses.

Comment: Yes but what do the values mean? I get a 1d array of 4 values. The first one is model.intercept_. What are the other 3 and are any of them the beta values I need? The documentation doesn't seem to help...

Comment: Ah ok, I think I got it now. Thank you

Comment: Its weird formatting, why isn't there [N][2] array. bet0 and beta1 for each metric